# Get data from Laravel Nova API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I need to know if there is a way to use Laravel Nova's APIs. I could find some at / /nova-api//

But there is nothing in docs about that. It would be a great help if I could call them outside of Nova, for my mobile app for example.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for that? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure there is a doc, but you can get data from /nova-api/your-resource, /nova-api/your-resource/filters, /nova-api/your-resource/actions, etc.

Comment: thanks, but how do i mimic the login and authenticate every request? there are XSRF TOKENS every where. thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: I just test the backend, the front end, I don't know. For backend, just use: $this->actingAs($this->user);

Comment: Did not understand that... but thanks anyway...

Comment: I meant "not" the front end ^^. If you just test the API, you can use actingAs method to log as a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Laravel Testing for testing nova-apis.

```
 $response = $this
            ->actingAs($user)
            ->getJson('/nova-api/user/');
```

Above code will return JSON data for Users for Nova User resource.

Comment: yep. it will work. Maybe with /nova-api/users/